# Will Homebrew install of mongodb overwrite existing databases?

Tags: mongodb, installation, homebrew

I want to reinstall mongodb on my mac using the following commands:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community
```

If I do this, will I lose the current databases in my existing mongodb install?

**Edit**

To clarify, the previous installation was done via HomeBrew as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where your existing database files are stored, whether mongo was installed via Homebrew previously, and if so, which version was installed.

Homebrew will install mongodb into `/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/{version}` (4.4.0 as of this writing) and symlink the binaries into `/usr/local/bin`. It will not modify an installation performed by another means and any existing databases will be untouched as long as they're not in the same path as this installation. You would be able to load them with the Homebrew version with no issues.

You will need to consider your $PATH if you plan to leave both mongodb versions installed - if the Homebrew path (/usr/local/bin) is after the path of your current installation then the old binary will run. Homebrew usually takes care of this for you, but something to watch out for if you have any strange behaviour. Check the location of your current binaries by running `which mongod`.

To stay on the safe side, you should make a copy of your existing data files before you [re,un]install.

Comment: Please see my update: I did the previous installation via HomeBrew as well, but because (for some reason) mongodump was not available at the  command line, I wanted to reinstall mongodb so I could get access to that function.